# Finding duplicate row using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

**Person**

```
Name        City

Joe         Houston   
Jerry       London    
Alex        Houston   
Jerry       London
```

How to return duplicate row using LINQ  like

**Sql**

```
SELECT name, city, count(*)
FROM collection
GROUP BY name,city 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

I tried something

```
var qry =
    from m in context.Collections
    group m by new { m.city, m.name } into grp
    select new { rp = grp.Count() > 2 };
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a where, not a select:

```
var qry =  from m in context.Collections
           group m by new { m.city, m.name } into grp
           where grp.Count() > 1
           select grp.Key;
```

Comment: Hi John,I want to ask question. Is it possible to select duplicate rows key and value?

Answer (score 1):

Building on **@Jon Skeet**'s answer with a "one liner" alternative that returns the duplicate values, not just the keys:

```
var duplicates = db.Collections.GroupBy(m => new { m.city, m.name })
                               .Where(a => a.Count() > 1)
                               .SelectMany(a => a.ToList());
```