# Found Duplicate record in excel sheet using c# .net

Tags: c#, linq, excel, lambda

I've a datatable that has been filled by excel sheet, it has lots of product id's and some other data. I want to check if there is any duplicate product id in my datatable and tell user that these prodcuts ids are duplicates or something like that.

Lmbda, Linq , Looping anything will do.

Thanks

Comment: Check out this SO question - [LINQ to DataTable, finding duplicate rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584119/linq-to-datatable-finding-duplicate-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified version of another answer [C# Linq finding duplicate row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890427/c-linq-finding-duplicate-row):

```
var qry =  from p in Products
           group p by p.productID into grp
           where grp.Count() > 1
           select grp;

foreach (var product in qry)
{
    // Do something as needed/desired
}
```

Products is the DataTable, productID is the product ID; substitute appropriate names from your code as needed.  I haven't tested this, but it should at least get you pointed in the right direction.